# At.js @mention - C# Web API

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, at.js

I am using https://github.com/ichord/At.js library to achieve autocomplete.

But it shows a list of "undefined" dropdown when I am using remoteFilter like they said in https://github.com/ichord/At.js/wiki/How-to-use-remoteFilter .

Model:

```
public class CaseHistory
{
    public int CaseHistoryId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Symptom/Disease")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter symptom or disease")]
    public string SymptomOrDisease { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

API action code:

```
   private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET api/CaseHistories
    public IQueryable<CaseHistory> GetCaseHistories()
    {
        return db.CaseHistories;
    }
```

Here is my code in the razor view:

```
    var myUrl = 'https://localhost:44301/api/CaseHistories';

    $('#inputor').atwho({
    at: ":",
    callbacks: {
        /*
         It function is given, At.js will invoke it if local filter can not find any data
         query [String] matched query
         callback [Function] callback to render page.
        */
        remoteFilter: function(query, callback) {
            $.getJSON(myUrl, { q: query }, function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Please share the Api action code

Comment: @zaitsman I have added Api action code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code in the controller to be:

```
   public dynamic GetCaseHistories()
    {
        return db.CaseHistories.Select(x => x.SymptomOrDisease).ToList();
    }
```

The issue is that the parameter you pass to callback should be array of strings.

If you really wanted to do this in js:

```
    var myUrl = 'https://localhost:44301/api/CaseHistories';

    $('#inputor').atwho({
    at: ":",
    callbacks: {
        /*
         It function is given, At.js will invoke it if local filter can not find any data
         query [String] matched query
         callback [Function] callback to render page.
        */
        remoteFilter: function(query, callback) {
            $.getJSON(myUrl, { q: query }, function (data) {
            var targetData = [];
                for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
                        targetData.push(data[i].SymptomOrDisease);
                }
                callback(targetData);
            });
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using jquery in the view without changing the controller?

Comment: See the updated to the answer. however, this is really not so efficient as you are effectively selecting data from db that you will then discard.

Comment: I see. Then I will go for selecting data for db option. One more thing, when I am using 'api/CaseHistories' as myUrl, the url becomes https://localhost:44301/Prescriptions/Create. Here prescription is the controller for current view[this view above] How can I pass only api/CaseHistories as the url without using full url like in the code above?

Comment: you should be able to simply use `var myUrl = '/api/CaseHistories';` that would ask for the api at the root of the host the user is viewing the page on